# Upload file to a sharepoint using python

Tags: python, sharepoint, ntlm

I'm trying to upload a file to a sharepoint site with a python script. It works when i'm doing a system call to use cURL, but it won't works using python various libraries. For some reason, I would like to not do system calls in my program.

I tried using the Requests and Requests_NTLM libraries. I also tried using urllib2 library.

For the requests library, it send back a 200 status code but when i'm checking on the sharepoint, the file isn't there.

Working code using cURL via system call:

```py
import os

myCmd= "curl -T testcron.log http://mysharepoint.com/docshare/path/to/the/folder/ --ntlm -u 'user:password'"
os.system(myCmd)
```

Code that send back status code 200 but the file does not appear in sharepoint using requests library:

```py
import requests
from requests_ntlm import HttpNtlmAuth

url='http://mysharepoint.com/docshare/path/to/the/folder/'
files = {'file': open('testcron.log', 'rb')}

session = requests.Session()
session.auth = HttpNtlmAuth('user','password')
r=session.post(url,files=files)
print r.status_code
```

Is there a way with requests (or other python lib) to upload a file to a sharepoint folder ?

Many thanks !

Comment: Had you analyzed a real request from browser? You only have to replicate it

Comment: I did much pcap and analyzed them. If i reuse with requests the "put" method that is using cURL, i got a 500 error code.
Strangely, in the curl pcap, i can see that after ntlm negociation, the sharepoint send a code 100 "continue" what I never succeed to reproduce with requests

Comment: Analyze with devTools... copy as curl

Comment: It seems that cURL is using webdav to upload the file, what requests isn't doing. any suggestion to use webdav with requests ?

Comment: Just solved this issue (after some days of investigations...).
i had to add the filename after the URL, as below: 
r=session.put(url + 'output.xlsx',files=files)

Thanks for your help on this, today i learned !

Comment: Nice to hear it Pescadito, self-learn will make you go far. Un saludo

Comment: I tried to use the same code but I am getting status code 403. any suggestions??